# Shell script to call daemon - DAEMON: command not found

Tags: shell, ubuntu, daemon

Currently I can start a custom server like this:

```
cd /home/admin/service/build && ./service visual.dat
```

I'm trying to make a shell script to make a daemon. I tried many things...

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cd /home/admin/service/build
DAEMON = "./service"
daemon_OPT="service.dat"
...
```

The response is:

```
admin@service:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/servicedaemon start
/etc/init.d/servicedaemon: line 3: DAEMON: command not found
```

Well, how to launch the service from the daemon like I did from the shell ? It's probably a path issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to remove the spaces around "=":

```
DAEMON="./service"
```

Now it seems that it tries to run a command called DAEMON instead of the actual application.

Comment: Wouah !!! I didn't think spaces can be important ! Sorry I'm new to shell scripts !